# How to initialize and define const string with Reflection.Emit

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I need help with .Net `Reflection.Emit`.

Need create simple `Assembly` with `public struct` and `string` field in it. Field must be constant and I also need define it. In all I need get `Assembly` that hold inside something like this:

```
namespace n {
    struct Alpha {
        public const string DATA = "Alpha";
    }
}
```

I don't understand how create `string` field and how define it.

At this moment i am write this code:

```
private static void Generate()
{
    var an = new AssemblyName("Beta") { Version = new Version("1.0.0.0") };
    var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
    var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("BetaModule", "Beta.dll");
    var tb = mb.DefineType("n.Beta", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(System.ValueType));
    // What I need do after it? How I understand from MSDN I need call DefineInitializedData method but i am not shure how do it.
    tb.CreateType();
    ab.Save("Beta.dll");
}
```

---

Solution:

```
private static void Generate() {
    var an = new AssemblyName("Beta") { Version = new Version("1.0.0.0") };
    var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
    var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("BetaModule", "Beta.dll");
    var tb = mb.DefineType("n.Beta", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(System.ValueType));
    var fb = tb.DefineField("DATA", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Literal);
    fb.SetConstant("Beta");
    tb.CreateType();
    ab.Save("Beta.dll");
}
```

I am not sure that it is 100% correct, but it works. BTW, it would be great if some one will check it. Maybe I made some mistakes...

Comment: please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll see that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. One result of that is that we don't use signatures, tag lines, "hello", or "thanks".

Answer (score 2):

Constants have no meaning in IL.  They are compiled by the compiler, it emits their literal value into the IL.  You are playing the role of the compiler when you use Reflect.Emit, you have emit the value yourself.

Which isn't a real problem, you can just declare the const in your own code.  And emit the ldc or ldstr opcode whenever the const needs to be used.

Comment: If i am understand you right i cant make const by emit but i can make readonly field and declare it in constructor. Right?

Comment: Think this through a bit: why not declare the const in your own code?

Comment: Ok, readonly field will also good. But what i need do to make it?

1. Create field by DefineField method or by DefineInitializedData?
2. Create default constructor for struct
3. In constructor define field

All right?

What flag i need use to create readonly field? FieldAttributes.Literal?